# What is the function of 就是

Tags: grammar, usage, meaning-in-context, word, sentence-structure

What does 就  是mean and how do we use it I have seen many times people using like in this sentence 就是关于爱情的 so what does 就是really means

Answer (score 2):

就 has many meanings, In different context, '就是' could mean 'is exactly' ; 'then it is' ; 'just/ only'

Example:

- 他最怕的话题[**就是**]关于爱情的话题 = The topic he afraid the most, [**is exactly**] the topic about love
- 讨论完关于工作的话题, 接下来[**就是**]关于爱情的话题 = Finished discussing the topic about job,  next [**then it is**] the topic about love
- 他什么书都看，[**就是**]关于爱情的他不看 = He read any kind of book, [**just**/ **only**] the ones about love he doesn't read

Comment: Thanks it helped a lot

Answer (score 1):

就是 denote some situation or things is true, you can think the component this way 就是[other description], where [other description] is description which is true. In your example, 就是关于爱情的(就是[other description], where [other description] is 关于爱情的) ((something) is about (other thing) of love). 关于爱情的 is true. It is used to show that something is about other thing of love.

Answer (score 1):

就是 could of course be used on its own in everyday conversations as an exclamatory comment, like, when someone says, 呆在家里以防止冠状病毒covid-19传播是非常无聊的, and your comment, 就是！！！

呆在家里 = staying home

以防止  =  to prevent

冠状病毒 = (Guānzhuàng bìngdú) = Coronavirus

Covid-19传播 = Covid-19 spread

是非常无聊的 = (shì fēi cháng wú liáo de) is very boring.

就是！！！ = exactly!!!

Answer (score 1):

就是 bascially means Yes/it is or Just/only or "Just yes"(exactly)

就是关于爱情的 means Just about love
(or Only about love, meaning not more than love)

Informally, you can treat 就是 as Yas. It can be used as exclamation.

Answer (score 0):

> What does 就 是mean?

就是就是就是的意思！：）：）

这就是关于爱情的问题。
This is precisely because of problems in amour.

就是：just, exactly, that is， precisely

How you translate 就是 will depend on your context.